# What Android Tablets are compatible with 5 GHz 802.11 networks?

Tags: wi-fi, tablet

All too often, I've seen manufacturers go the "cheap route" when putting out products that they can call "802.11n compatible".  Most of the time, what they aren't telling you is that the "compatible" device only works on 2.4 GHz networks.

As I'm potentially going to be in the market for a new Android-based Tablet in the near future, and I have an 802.11n 5 GHz network at home, I'm wondering which of the devices currently available will be able to operate on that network?

Answer (score 2):

I have a Galaxy Tab which works perfectly with my Belkin PlayMax on 5GHZ.